# Exclude "AND" when parsing list of ingredients with regex

Tags: php, regex

I've searched around quite a bit and can't seem to find a way to get something like "AND" to be excluded in an entry like the following:

> TOMATO PUREE (WATER, TOMATO PASTE), CARAMEL COLOR, POTASSIUM SORBATE AND CALCIUM DISODIUM EDTA, MOLASSES, CORN SYRUP, SUGAR, SPICES, TAMARIND, NATURAL FLAVOR.

My current regex string can catch everything, but I don't know how to get it to split "POTASSIUM SORBATE" and "CALCIUM DISODIUM EDTA". Here's what I have:

```
[\(,\)\s]*\s*([^,\)\(\.]+)\s*[\.,\)\s\(]
```

This is in PHP by the way, and I don't want to split it after the matches have already been found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Code:

```
$text = 'TOMATO PUREE (WATER, TOMATO PASTE), CARAMEL COLOR, POTASSIUM SORBATE AND CALCIUM DISODIUM EDTA, MOLASSES, CORN SYRUP, SUGAR, SPICES, TAMARIND, NATURAL FLAVOR.';

$array = preg_split('/\)?, | \(|, | AND |\./', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

var_dump($array);
```

## Output:

```
array(13) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "TOMATO PUREE"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "WATER"
  [2]=>
  string(12) "TOMATO PASTE"
  [3]=>
  string(13) "CARAMEL COLOR"
  [4]=>
  string(17) "POTASSIUM SORBATE"
  [5]=>
  string(21) "CALCIUM DISODIUM EDTA"
  [6]=>
  string(8) "MOLASSES"
  [7]=>
  string(10) "CORN SYRUP"
  [8]=>
  string(5) "SUGAR"
  [9]=>
  string(6) "SPICES"
  [10]=>
  string(8) "TAMARIND"
  [11]=>
  string(14) "NATURAL FLAVOR"
}
```

Comment: Looks like we have a winner! Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I got this:

```
$str = "TOMATO PUREE (WATER, TOMATO PASTE), CARAMEL COLOR, POTASSIUM SORBATE AND CALCIUM DISODIUM EDTA, MOLASSES, CORN SYRUP, SUGAR, SPICES, TAMARIND, NATURAL FLAVOR.";

$array = preg_split("/\s*(,|AND)\s*/i", $str);

print_r($array);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => TOMATO PUREE (WATER
    [1] => TOMATO PASTE)
    [2] => CARAMEL COLOR
    [3] => POTASSIUM SORBATE
    [4] => CALCIUM DISODIUM EDTA
    [5] => MOLASSES
    [6] => CORN SYRUP
    [7] => SUGAR
    [8] => SPICES
    [9] => TAMARIND
    [10] => NATURAL FLAVOR.
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Ohaal had a slightly better solution, so I gave him the shiny checkmark instead.

Answer (score 0):

Truth solution is the one, if you want to go with regex. It also take care of white spaces on the same time.

if you don't understand regular expressions, as alternative solution you can:

1. replace each ' AND ' with comma
2. split string to elements using comma separator

   ```
   $array = preg_split(",", str_replace(" AND ", ",", $str));
   ```

This solution use simple string functions that you should be able to work with.

At the end you may want to delete unwanted white space characters using function [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

Comment: I understand regular expressions plenty well, thank you very much.